# Measuring distance of image pixel from different neighboring polylines?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I'm going to measure the distance between a given image pixel and a series of neighboring polylines, consisting of 15 different types of roads. In other words, I'm looking for a solution with which I can measure the distance of the pixel from all the 15 types of roads, not only the nearest one.

How can I do it in ArcGIS?

Comment: You can't do this directly from a raster, you will need to export your raster to points then separate the roads by their type to individual feature classes then using Generate Near Table create a table for each of the road types, add fields for the closest *by type*, join by attributes to each near table and Field Calculate the distances. This requires an advanced license. If your count of points is small enough you can perform a point to raster (use FID/OBJECTID) and join the feature class distance table to the raster attribute table.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelStimson for your help. I'll test it to see if it works for me.

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please decide which of the GIS products mentioned you want to ask about.  By asking about more than one you are effectively asking multiple questions which goes against the [Tour]. You should then describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: @PolyGeo I revised the question to make it more specific. Thank you.

Comment: I've removed the ArcPy tag because you have presented no code.  You have a [tag:spatial-analyst] tag but are you using the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst to try to do this?